# NodeJS: Error: spawn EINVAL

Tags: node.js

**Env:**

> ```
> [root@etone46 backups]# uname -a
> Linux etone46 2.6.18-53.el5xen #1 SMP Wed Oct 10 16:48:44 EDT 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> [root@etone46 backups]# node -v
> v0.8.6
> ```

**the code is copy from node doc.**

```
var util  = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        ls    = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

        ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
              console.log('stdout: ' + data);
        });

        ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
              console.log('stderr: ' + data);
        });

        ls.on('exit', function (code) {
              console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
        });
```

**got error:**

> [root@etone46 backups]# node 1.js
>
> ```
> child_process.js:790
>     throw errnoException(errno, 'spawn');
>           ^
> Error: spawn EINVAL
>     at errnoException (child_process.js:838:11)
>     at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:790:11)
>     at exports.spawn (child_process.js:614:9)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/backups/1.js:3:14)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
>     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
> ```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/iSZIj-MtCtg

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/ePqzZ7rPdzU%5B1-25%5D